# Problem in hosting Dot net Core on windows server with IIS (nop commerce)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to host nopcommerce 4.10 on windows server IIS. I have installed .net core hosting bundle, .net Sdk and also set its environment variable c++ redistributable package is also installed. But I am still getting this screen. I have also enables stdout but does not getting any log. [image: ScreenImage]

I've tried many solutions from forums and all other site but still getting same issue.

Web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<modules>
  <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
 resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
  <!-- When deploying on Azure, make sure that "dotnet" is installed and the 
  path to it is registered in the PATH environment variable or specify the 
 full path to it -->
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" 
stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600" 
/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
     </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you install the latest nopCommerce version? I also faced same issue with you, but when I installed latest version, everything works perfectly.

Comment: It's latest 4.10

Comment: How about the .net core? Have you install latest .net core version?

Answer (score 1):

%LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% did not get replaced, it should be something like

```
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\Nop.Web.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

Comment: I replaced old one with yours.. still the issue is resides.